# How to conditionally iterate a for loop with if loop?

Tags: r

I want my 2nd for loop to use a conditional vector, but when I tried putting an if loop in the vector area, the code just iterates over the 1st value in the vector and leaves the rest

```
for (product in c('apple','mango','orange')) {
  for (store in ifelse(product %in% c('mango','orange'),
                         c('KGS','ADA'),'ADA')) {
    for (sold in c('1','2','3')) {
      sp_table[nrow(sp_table)+1,] <- NA
      sp_table[nrow(sp_table),'Store:id'] <- store
      sp_table[nrow(sp_table),'Product:id'] <- paste(store,product,sold,sep = '_')
      
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other possibility of doing this other than using an if loop before for loop, since this would require looping inside both the if and else conditions and also calling all the columns in both places.

Comment: Hey, some sample data would help us to help you.  calling dput() on your data and posting the output here is a good place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't use conditions as loop control! In your case, `ifesle` retuns a vector of `FALSE/TRUE` and only `product == "mango"` will return true. This is the 1st value in the `ifelse` vector. Therefore...

Comment: `for(store in c("mango", etc, "ADA")); if(store == product){sp instructions loop}`.